# Android: Select data from SQLite database - advice

Tags: android

Please give me advice, what is the efficient way to select data from database if I have query like `SELECT * FROM order_list WHERE order_number = ?` In table I have more entries (in my case) with common order number and I'd like to create List for entries with same order number and then shot it in `ListView`. I don't know if it is efficient first select all order numbers and then in foreach loop select and create `List<Item>` or exists something better. I've tried find some example but unsuccessfully. How should I solve this problem? Thank you. I appreciate every help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can use the same you are thinking like this:**

```
"select col1,col2,col3 from table   WHERE order_number = ? ", new String[]{YOUR_VARIABLE_HERE};
```

For example:

```
 public Object[] getData(String Id) {
    Cursor c = null;
    ArrayList<String> arrayListProductName = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> arrayListProductId = new ArrayList<String>();
    db=helper.getWritableDatabase();
    c = db.rawQuery("select distinct  Column1,Column2 from Table1inner join Table2 on Table1.anyId = Table2.anyId  Table2.Id = ?", new String[]{Id});   
    c.moveToFirst();
    while(!c.isAfterLast())
    {
        arrayListProductName.add(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Column1")));
        arrayListProductId.add(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Column2 ")));
        c.moveToNext();
    }
    c.close();
    db.close();
    return new Object[]{arrayListProductName,arrayListProductId};
    }
```

**And in your Activity class:**

```
helper = new YourDatabaseHelper(this);

Object[] objectScheme = merchandisingHelper.getData(retId);
arrayListSchemeProductName = (ArrayList<String>) objectScheme[0];
arrayListSchemeProductId = (ArrayList<String>) objectScheme[1];
```

Hope this will help you.

Thanks

Comment: selectionArgs in query can contain only one argument? I mean if I want select in the same time items where order_number is 1,2,...,n? Is it possible do sth WHERE sth, new String[] {someArray[]}

Comment: yes you can have multiple args. **See** where id1 = ? and id2 = ? and id3 = ?,new String[] {ID1_VAL,ID2_VAL,ID3_VAL,}

Comment: you just have to take care of the first **?** value should at at first place in new String[] {FIRST_ARGS}.

Answer (score 0):

Use `GROUPBY` in `SQL`

```
SELECT *
FROM table_name
WHERE column_name = yourvalue
GROUP BY your_columnname
```

The `GROUP BY` is used in conjunction with the aggregate functions to group the result-set by one or more columns. In your case it will group your records based on your `order number`.After grouped you can assign to your list view or what ever you want.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want to know if it's more efficient to :

1. filter using a `WHERE order_number = ?` clause
2. load everything, then filter in a loop.

Then 1 is a much better solution, it will avoid a lot of unnecessary object creation. If you have a lot of rows it may be interesting to add an index on the `order_number` column.

If you want to show the result in a `Listview` the best solution is to connect the `SQLiteCursor` to the `ListView`, using a [SimpleCursorAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.html).
This is very efficient because you only have to load data when the `ListView` needs it.